# After lifting state up for input fields, not able to enter anything in fields

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs, I am trying to create two components with hooks one which will hold sate and other will be kind of presentational component, which will use  to set state.

Problem: when i try to give state value as props to child and use onClick function to set it to event.target.value, i am not able to enter anything in the fields, I have multiple filed with multiple state, one state for each input field. I am not  sure why its not working.
Also, I know it will work if i just use one component, and have state in the same component, but than i will not be able separate state from presentational component.

```
 //componetone
    const [left_value, setLeft_value] =useState()
    const [right_value, setRight_value] =useState()
    const [operator, setOperator] =useState()
    

//componentTwo

 <div>
                    <TextField
                        label="Left Number"
                        type="number"
                        name={"left_value"}
                        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                        variant="filled"
                        // onChange={(e) => setLeft_value(e.target.value)}
                        onChange={(e) => props.setLeft_value(e.target.value)}


                    />
                </div>
 <div>
                    <TextField
                        label="Right Number"
                        name={"comparison_operator"}
                        type="number"
                        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                        variant="filled"
                        onChange={(e) => props.setOperator(e.target.value)}
                        // onChange={(e) => setRight_value(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>

 <div>
                    <TextField
                        label="Right Number"
                        name={"right_value"}
                        type="number"
                        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                        variant="filled"
                        onChange={(e) => props.setRight_value(e.target.value)}
                        // onChange={(e) => setRight_value(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass a `value` prop?

Comment: I'm not sure what the TextField component is, so, I have no idea how that component works internally. But assuming it's just a regular input, you should pass a value to the TextField. So for your RightNumber textfield you should also always pass `value={props.right_value}`. The functionality of inputs in React is pretty wel documented here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html